# OpenGL vs Quartz/CG on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, quartz-graphics

In our current app, some consultants wrote code in OpenGL to make things look nice.  Basically mimicing a UITableView, goes horizontal instead of vertical, and of course prettier.  I was reading through a Core Animation book and they said that with Core Animation, you could mimic Apple's Cover Flow navigation.  To me, that looks nice enough.

Does anyone know if any of that is done in OpenGL or just Quartz and CoreGraphics?

Secondly, (here's the open-ended question), but if we were to redesign something to mimic Apple's cover flow, assuming it was not in OpenGL ES, would that be less memory intensive and perform better?  It seems like our app runs out of memory rather quickly in its current state since it's pushing a lot of data through the horizontal table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of a Core Animation layer (text, shapes, images, ...) is rendered with Quartz, but the rendering of the layer itself is done by OpenGL, so rendering performance shouldn't be a problem.
Core Animation might use less memory, because it can release the content of invisible layers (or table cells in your case).